# How come people that are not following me sometimes retweet my tweets?

Tags: twitter

Sometimes I see people re-twitting a tweet I sent, and I have no idea how they saw it as they are not following me.

Is it because they have some keyword search open and I happen to use one of those words? What are the different ways someone can see a tweet I send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already identified one mechanism - search, either something you tweeted or even your name.

They could have picked up your tweet from the Twitter home page.

You can see the lists of all people - not just those you are following. This shows all the tweets of people in that list.

One of your followers could already have retweeted you - though in this case you should see the original retweet too.

Comment: They may have retweeted it from someone who does follow you.

Comment: @Al - definitely, I've done that before.